# Deeplink between MS Teams App and other MS Teams channels

Tags: office365, deep-linking, microsoft-teams

I would like to provide links in my MS Teams App as Tab to other Channels. MS Teams offers deeplinks ([How it works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab)). However when a user clicks on it, it opens always a dialog to ask where to open Teams(App or Browser). Nevertheless, for a better UX the link should switch to the correct channel immediately without the dialog.

I tried using the ms teams schemes (msteams://). Unfortunately the link produce an error in MS Teams. `Requests to the server were blocked by an extension.` I have no further ideas how it could work.

Is there another opportunity to navigate between MS Teams apps and Channel in MS Teams without open the dialog?

Comment: This works smoothly when you deeplink from a bot. From tab, deeplink takes you to browser first. We are working on fixing this flow.

Comment: A workaround is to use JS with window.open('msteams://xyz)

Answer (score 0):

You can used `microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink` api to deep link from Tab html page.

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script src= 'https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.6.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
         
        window.openDeepLink = function(tabName) {
            microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/app/f46ad259-0fe5-4f12-872d-c737b174bcb4");
         
        }
         
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="openDeepLink()">Deep link</button>
</body>
</html>
```

`